# Ensembling multiple model predictions in Keras triggering retracing warning

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, ensemble-learning

I'm trying to generate 4 different types of predictions using four TensorFlow models that are built on similar architectures. When I call the `model.predict()` function four times using the same features, I get the following warning:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:5 out of the last 9 calls to <function Model.make_predict_function.<locals>.predict_function at 0x2b18970e88c0> triggered tf.function retracing. Tracing is expensive and the excessive number of tracings could be due to (1) creating @tf.function repeatedly in a loop, (2) passing tensors with different shapes, (3) passing Python objects instead of tensors. For (1), please define your @tf.function outside of the loop. For (2), @tf.function has experimental_relax_shapes=True option that relaxes argument shapes that can avoid unnecessary retracing. For (3), please refer to https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/performance#python_or_tensor_args and https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function for  more details.
WARNING:tensorflow:6 out of the last 10 calls to <function Model.make_predict_function.<locals>.predict_function at 0x2b189734ab90> triggered tf.function retracing. Tracing is expensive and the excessive number of tracings could be due to (1) creating @tf.function repeatedly in a loop, (2) passing tensors with different shapes, (3) passing Python objects instead of tensors. For (1), please define your @tf.function outside of the loop. For (2), @tf.function has experimental_relax_shapes=True option that relaxes argument shapes that can avoid unnecessary retracing. For (3), please refer to https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/performance#python_or_tensor_args and https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function for  more details.
WARNING:tensorflow:7 out of the last 11 calls to <function Model.make_predict_function.<locals>.predict_function at 0x2b189784be60> triggered tf.function retracing. Tracing is expensive and the excessive number of tracings could be due to (1) creating @tf.function repeatedly in a loop, (2) passing tensors with different shapes, (3) passing Python objects instead of tensors. For (1), please define your @tf.function outside of the loop. For (2), @tf.function has experimental_relax_shapes=True option that relaxes argument shapes that can avoid unnecessary retracing. For (3), please refer to https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/performance#python_or_tensor_args and https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function for  more details.
WARNING:tensorflow:7 out of the last 11 calls to <function Model.make_predict_function.<locals>.predict_function at 0x2b1897e1c440> triggered tf.function retracing. Tracing is expensive and the excessive number of tracings could be due to (1) creating @tf.function repeatedly in a loop, (2) passing tensors with different shapes, (3) passing Python objects instead of tensors. For (1), please define your @tf.function outside of the loop. For (2), @tf.function has experimental_relax_shapes=True option that relaxes argument shapes that can avoid unnecessary retracing. For (3), please refer to https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/performance#python_or_tensor_args and https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function for  more details.
```

Here is what I did when I loaded the models and made the predictions. The code is based on this tutorial: https://machinelearningmastery.com/stacking-ensemble-for-deep-learning-neural-networks/

```
model_1=load_model('./Models/model_1.hdf5')
model_2=load_model('./Models/model_2.hdf5')
model_3=load_model('./Models/model_3.hdf5')
model_4=load_model('./Models/model_4.hdf5')
models=[model_1,model_2,model_3,model_4]

# get prediction outputs for the four models
def get_predictions(features,models):
    return np.array([i.predict(features) for i in models])

preds=get_predictions(features,models)
```

How to I get rid of the warnings? Am I doing something wrong here? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using

> preds = m.predict(features)

Use:

> preds = m(features)

Answer (score 2):

Nobody answered last year, but I have just run into the same problem. The solution is to define the separate neural networks within a single Keras model. Training and calculation still occurs independently within each individual network and you can still take the mean of the individual outputs in the same way, but the retracing warning disappears and - more importantly - the performance is much better.

Comment: What do you mean by this? To declare them all within a single script?